# Is it possible to mark code to be compiled only in debug mode?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, f#

I've got a try catch (or with in F#) structures all over the code but I don't really need them in debug mode, it's easer for me to debug errors via VS debugger.

So I want to mark try catch codelines to be compiled only in release mode - is it possible or not ?

Comment: Why do you have the try/catch in code at all? What purpose do they server in release mode?

Comment: From my experience, having `try...catch` blocks "all over the code" usually indicates a rather bad architecture/design. Instead, I'm using global error handlers like [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx).

Comment: I know that it's better to handle all possible code mistakes without try catch... But I'm processing recived bytes and currently I found it easer to use try catch instead of analyse them before process.

Comment: Because exceptions don't need to jump all the way up to the application entry point depending on the situation?

Also, do you really want to make your code behave differently in debug or release mode?

Comment: I want to make release version clear from anything non-user-friendly.

Comment: Ok, I'm just not sure adding conditional compilation is the way to do user-friendly exception handling - you might make the code programmer-unfriendly instead.

Comment: You mention that it's easier for you to debug errors via VS debugger so you want disable the catch statements - you can get VS to break into the debugger when an exception is thrown (Debug menu -> Exceptions) which you might find easier than putting `#if` guards around everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can surround them with:

```
#if !DEBUG
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

No one mentioned about `ConditionalAttribute` that could be applied to a code block. For a false condition the code block (and all it's calls) are skipped from compilation step.

Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for are preprocessor commands like so:

```
#if !DEBUG
try {
#endif
code();
#if !DEBUG
}
catch(Exception)
{ dostuff(); }
#endif
```

MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`!` is not a preprocessor directive in F#, so you'll need to do:

```
#if DEBUG
#else
try
#endif

...

#if DEBUG
#else
with e -> ...
#endif
```

Comment: yes, I'm using #if RELEASE, but why there is nothing alike #if not DEBUG ?

Comment: Good question. I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Nensha there is; `#if !DEBUG`

Comment: Oh, seriously?! I were trying to understand it whole year after accepting the answer but things come real only after Marc's answer! :D

Comment: @Nensha 3 answers, including the accepted one, use the `#if !DEBUG` syntax

Answer (score 2):

you can use #if preprocessor command

```
#if !DEBUG
try {
#endif
// your "exceptional" code
#if !DEBUG
} catch { }
#endif
```